# Is this an Ethernet cable running to my alarm panel?

Tags: ethernet, cables, alarm

8 conductor cable, not plugged into anything nor terminated. Thank you!

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'd **like** to use it as an Ethernet cable and it is not currently being used for anything, so I want to see if I can just crimp Ethernet connector to it (and find the other end) if it'll work as an Ethernet cable without causing any problems.

I believe that jacket reads "24 AWG C(ETL) US LISTED 2003548 TYPE CMR/MPR FT4 BKC 118163 25BCB FEET ETL." Photos below:

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

[image: Photo 3]

Comment: It's an ethernet-type cable.  But that doesn't necessarily mean it's being used for ethernet.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post to comment that I'd LIKE to use it as an Ethernet cable and it is not currently used for anything. I just want to see if it will cause some problems if I do this (won't work) as the jacket doesn't specifically state Cat5 or Cat6 etc.

Comment: If it doesn't actually have a CAT rating, then it may not actually be rated for Ethernet.  The only markings I can see relate to the insulation.

Comment: You'd have to see if there are individual twisted pairs (with or without shields), or whether it's a bundle of untwisted wires. If twisted pairs, you *might* be able to run ethernet over a short distance. If it is not stamped Cat5 or Cat4, I don't think there's much you can do over anything more than a few feet. (Your mileage may vary)

Comment: Ok, thanks. At the very tip there are 8 untwisted conductors but I could strip it and look a little farther. The alarm guy texted "sure can use for Internet" but I'm a little skeptical (I've never interacted with him or used him but he appears to have serviced for prior owners)

Comment: Where does the other end of this cable go?

Comment: That is a great question. The alarm guy claims it is inside the "structural panel" which is the box with all the phone and cable connections for the house, and there is one unterminated yellow 8 conductor cable there, but the markings on the cable also seem different, so I don't know if it is really the same cable.

Answer (score 1):

So I think it actually IS an Ethernet cable.

Looking farther into the hole on the cable markings, I see "ETL VERIFIED TO TIA/EIA 568B."

However, I think I don't know where the cable comes out on the other side. The ones in the "structural panel" that are yellow are all rated CM and this one is CMR, so I don't think it is the same cable.

Comment: TIA/EIA 568B is a family of specifications, under which Cat 3,5 and 6 cables fall. I doubt it's any of those without the marking. It does have twisted pairs, it has standard paired colour coding, could be balanced, likely not shielded, might carry old ethernet, and my guess it's for your alarm's phone hookup to a monitoring service.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I bought a tone and probe kit to trace out some of the other wiring (worked great) and wherever this cable is going, it definitely doesn't go to the "structural panel" that the alarm guy said. Oh well...

Comment: So, for posterity's sake, I toned out the cable in the attic, and it is definitely not going to the structural wiring box but rather down a conduit near the back of the house which I assume is running to the phone demarc box.

Comment: Also, the cable portion that comes out in attic says "Cat 5e" so it is definitely an Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fire rated ethernet cable and the other end is probably near the duct manifold where a fire sensor should be.